# Image overlay on video between two time using mobile-ffmpeg android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to add image overlay on video using  "mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4" library but faced following error:

```
Error when evaluating the expression 'between(t' for enable' error.
```

I have a class that create overlay filter for adding image:

```
class ImageFilter {

static String getFilter(String input, String output, ArrayList<ExtraTL> listImage, int order){
    String filter="";
    for (int i=0; i<listImage.size(); i++){
        ImageHolder image = listImage.get(i).imageHolder;
        int index = i+order;
        String in = i==0?input:"[out"+index+"]";
        String out = i==listImage.size()-1?output:"[out"+(index+1)+"];";
        filter += prepareImage(image, index);
        filter += addImage(in, out, image, index);
    }
    return filter;
}

private static String prepareImage(ImageHolder image, int index){
    return "["+index+":v]scale="+image.width+":"
                +image.height+",rotate="+image.rotate+":c=none:ow=rotw("+image.rotate
                +"):oh=roth("+image.rotate+")[ov"+index+"];";
}

private static String addImage(String input, String output, ImageHolder image, int index){
    return input+"[ov"+index+"]overlay="+image.x
            +":"+image.y+":enable='between(t,"+image.startInTimeLineSec +","
            +image.endInTimeLineSec +")'"+output;
}`
```

FFMPEG Command used:

```
-loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/OP_Video_Editor/.temp/background.png -ss 0.0 -t 21.18 -i /storage/emulated/0/OP_Video_Editor/.temp/1614097633623.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/OP_Video_Editor/.resource/sticker_i02.png -filter_complex [1:v]crop=640:360:0:0[crop];[crop]scale=1280:720[v_scale];color=black:1280x720,fps=30[bgr0];[bgr0][0:v]overlay[bgr];[bgr][v_scale]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v1];[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.0[a1];[v1][a1]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[v][a];[a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.0[a0];[a0]amix=inputs=1:duration=longest:dropout_transition=1[outAudio];[2:v]scale=333:333,rotate=-0.0:c=none:ow=rotw(-0.0):oh=roth(-0.0)[ov2];[v][ov2]overlay=333.33334:333.33334:enable='between(t,0.0,10.0)'[inText] -map [inText] -map [outAudio] -format yuva420p -preset ultrafast -video_track_timescale 90k -b:v 2000k -c:v libx264 -bufsize 64k -c:a aac -bsf aac_adtstoasc -strict -2 -y /storage/emulated/0/videoExport/videoplayback_22_21_28_18_44_10.mp4
```

Also my log when I run program is:

```
'2021-03-03 17:26:32.165 11664-11830/com.hecorat.azplugin2 E/mobile-ffmpeg: [overlay @ 0xdc5f3b80] [Eval @ 0xc5bd6b70] Missing ")" or too many args in "between(t"

2021-03-03 17:26:32.167 11664-11830/com.hecorat.azplugin2 E/mobile-ffmpeg: [overlay @ 0xdc5f3b80] Error when evaluating the expression "between(t" for enable'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Quote/escape the commas in `enable`.

Comment: If you found a solution, instead of adding it to your question consider adding it as an answer by using the "Post Your Answer" button. It can help you gain reputation points so you can eventually do more on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try inserting a ` before the comma in between(t,0.0,10.0), otherwise the comma will be interpreted as a filter separator.

With guidance @slhck; I replace

```
enable='between(t,"+image.startInTimeLineSec +","
        +image.endInTimeLineSec +")'
```

with

```
enable='between(t\\,"+image.startInTimeLineSec +"\\,"
        +image.endInTimeLineSec +")'
```

and it works.